# How to filter a date that is before a certain date using FetchXml?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, fetchxml

I am currently using the Advanced Find in CRM 2011, and I can't seem to find a way to filter a Date field that is before a certain date. The closest operator that I could find was "on-or-before", but I need it to be before that date and not on it.

Comment: so use on-or-before an put the date minus a day

Comment: @GuidoPreite That is an alternative solution. If possible, I would like to use a before operator. I wanted to check to make sure I didn't miss it in my search.

Comment: Its described here
http://www.crmanswers.net/2013/05/on-or-before-and-on-or-after-conditions.html

Comment: @minohimself I already looked at that previously. If I am not mistaken, that doesn't solve my issue at hand.

Answer (score 2):

I use lt (less than) if I need to do it by time. Presumably you can use gt too.

```
<condition attribute='scheduledstart' operator='lt' value='2015-03-16 10:29' />
```

Comment: Not sure why they hide lt and gt in the Dynamics UI.

Answer (score 1):

Use the "lt" operator(less than). Unfortunately the Dynamics UI hides this operator, along with some others. They have on-or-before and on-or-after, like you mentioned. That is essentially "le" (less or equal) and "ge" (greater or equal).  Try FetchXML Builder for XRM Toolbox. It exposes all the operators and will generate the FetchXML for you, or even Odata if you need it.